# Do Plantimals exhale CO2 or just Oxygen?

Tags: xenobiology

If an animal could photosynthesize would it need to breathe since it makes its own?

Also if it does breathe, would it exhale CO2 or Oxygen?

Comment: plants emit co2 and oxygen so why would your things be any different.

Comment: Is it perpetually light on that world?

Comment: Plants breathe oxygen and produce carbon dioxide just like animals. But in daytime, plants *also* perform photosynthesis, which is a completely separate process, taking in carbon dioxide and releasing oxygen. On the balance, they produce more oxygen that what they consume. But on the other hand, plants are ... plants, and live with a very small amount of energy. Most animals need much more energy than what they could make by photosynthesis, so that a human sized animal, for example, would not be able to satisfy more than a very few percent of its energy needs from its green skin.

Comment: We need to know more about how your plantimals live. AlexP should turn that comment into an answer (it's right on topic) but I feel we need more parameters. If they mostly sit and do nothing, it will look a bit different than plants that are essentially green animals.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Trees exhale carbon dioxide. I know what you were taught in school, and they really do produce oxygen from photosynthesis, but since they use metabolism similar to animals, they use up that oxygen almost as soon as they make it. Only a few plants produce net oxygen (phytoplankton in the ocean). Your stuff will almost certainly only exhale carbon dioxide except in extraordinary circumstances.

Comment: Whichever the answer you choose as correct I would suggest you to consider a mechanism that brings _balance_ in the way that if they consume carbon dioxide you will need a mechanism that produces it, on the contrary if they consume oxygen there would need to be an even larger amount of plants to produce that, not necessarily on dry land, which would enrich the oceans, lakes and large bodies of water of such place

Answer (score 14):

To answer question one (and you're really only supposed to ask one question at a time on WBSE) the answer is *yes* they would have to have a respiratory system with the exception of only the smallest of invertebrates. This is because body mass is proportional to the cube of an animals linear size i.e. M (mass) = L(linear size) cubed.

Put simply, calculating an animal's volume by measuring its width x length x height gives you its approximate mass (assuming all animals have a more or less equal body density, approximating that of water.) So even if the animal is entirely covered with photosynthetic organelles those organelles won't be able to generate enough energy to feed its entire body mass.

This is part of the the reason plants have such high volume to mass ratios i.e. huge surface areas to mass compared to animals. It doesn't matter if it's a blade of grass or a redwood, they both have large surface areas in proportion to their mass and are only sustainable because they don't have to physically move location and a lot of their internal mass is inert supporting structure that doesn't require further energy input once it's grown and put in place.

As for your second question: plants also exhale (excrete CO2) because like animals they have a metabolism and have to convert food into energy to survive. During daylight hours they use sunlight and water to produce simple sugars for energy. This process splits water into its component hydrogen and oxygen atoms, the latter of which they excrete. But while doing this they also excrete CO2 because no matter the time of day their cells still need to 'burn' energy to survive. At night they excrete only CO2 because ... well, no sunlight!

Comment: To add to this, we can already see in the design of plants why it wouldn't work. Plants are famous for not moving. Though they create more O² than they need, it is still for an organism design that uses a fraction of energy compared to most moving animals.

Answer (score 6):

There are "plantimals" in real life. [Giant clams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_clam) photosynthesize for up to 70% of their energy needs. They don't really breathe, though, living underwater.

Like [Mon's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/253906/7784) describes, a plant takes up both O2 and CO2 from the environment and produces both. But it has to take up more CO2, because that carbon is used for the growth of a plant. So if you locked it up in an airtight container, it would exhaust CO2 and die.

Does a "plantimal" need a large surface area? Maybe. Giant clams don't have a large surface area. Instead they have [iridocytes](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmars.2020.00465/full), microscopic lenses that distribute sunlight across their tissue. But there are real-life animals with huge surface areas too. Insects don't breathe. Instead of a lung, they have a [network of tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Respiratory_system_of_insects) that let the air reach every cell.

Comment: Quick point. Technically insects do breath (respire) because they still need to absorb oxygen into their blood (hemolymph) and excrete CO2. They just have a different organ thats responsible for handling the gas excahnge is all.

Comment: @Mon: The hemolymph of insects does not carry oxygen. The insect respiratory system has fine divisions which take the air straight to the tissues.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks for reminding me. I forgot. Oxygen diffusion in insects is all about surface area. Hence the reason we no long have meter long cockroaches scuttling away when we turn the lights on suddenly in the kitchen. (Thankfully.) :)

Answer (score 3):

As a proof that plants still consume oxygen, look at the *roots* as an example. They do not photosynthesize. Neither do the leaves at night time. That is why growing plants in a pot or the garden, you must provide good drainage, or the roots will rot because they get no oxygen. (Decomposing organic matter in the soil depletes oxygen more quickly and anaerobic decomposition begins to take place). Primary producers, like plants and algae, produce some carbon dioxide for their metabolic processes, a process which consumes oxygen. However, oxygen production *dominates* over carbon dioxide production, which helps sustain a breathable atmosphere.

Photosynthesis produces starch and sugars. This is energy storage for times of lesser activity, such as night time and dormancy, and springing back to active growth to sprout the new leaves for the new growing season. Carbon dioxide is the byproduct of metabolizing the starch and sugars.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the type of plantimal to move a lot, it would probably mostly exhale CO2 and only get a small amount of its energy from photosynthesis. On the other hand, if it's the type of creature that mostly remains motionless and waits for its prey and only moves to get to more advantageous locations, it would probably be a net CO2 consumer and O2 producer.

Movement requires quite a lot of energy, which is why most photosynthesizing life is immobile. Anaerobic movement is possible, but it has limitations and side effects. Alcohol is, for instance, created from anaerobic processes, and it eventually kills the bacteria that turned sugar into alcohol in the first place.